# Android RelativeLayout: Show a list of ConstraintLayouts

Tags: android, list, android-relativelayout, layoutparams

I have a `ConstraintLayout` file called `R.layout.new_plan` which contains the Views needed to display a `PlanItem` object. I'd like to display a **list of** `R.layout.new_plan`'s in a `RelativeLayout` root view.

My `RelativeLayout` parent/root is like so:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_plan_items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        <!-- other properties here -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

In other words, I have a `List<PlanItem>` and I'd like to display this list, using a `R.layout.new_plan` view to display each `PlanItem`, in `rl_plan_items`. My current way of doing it is to loop for each `PlanItem` in the list, set `TextView`s in `R.layout.new_plan` according to the attributes of the current `PlanItem`, and adding it to `rl_plan_items` using `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` somehow.

The code is like this:

```
private fun PlanItem.addToRootView(rootView: RelativeLayout, pos: Int) {
    val planItemView: ConstraintLayout = inflater
        .inflate(R.layout.new_plan, rootView, false) as ConstraintLayout

    planItemView.id = pos

    with(planItemView) {
        tv_title.text = name
        tv_desc.setTextAndGoneIfEmpty(description)
        tv_date.text = getDateToDisplay(resources)
        tv_subject.setTextAndGoneIfEmpty(subject?.name)
    }

    val params = planItemView.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams

    val idOfBelow: Int = if (pos > 0) planItemView.id - 1 else rootView.id
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, idOfBelow)

    rootView.addView(planItemView, params)
}
```

in my fragment:

```
for (i in planItems.indices) {
    planItems[i].addToRootView(rl_plan_items, i)
}
```

This does show all PlanItems, but they are shown on top of each other, not going down to the bottom.

[image]

[image]

How can I display the plan item views in order going down, not crunched together?

Comment: Why don't use a recyclerview for this?

Comment: I do use recyclerview for each date, now for each date row i want to display a list of plans. I don't want the plan view to scroll.

Comment: You mean that each "holder" will be a list of textviews ? Using a linear-layout wouldn't make your life easier? If you really want to make each item to be a constraint layout, you will need to set the constraint between each item.

Comment: I see... I thought because the parent is a `RelativeLayout` i'd follow `RelativeLayout`'s way of aligning items at the bottom of each one.

Comment: use another recycle view inside each row as well

Comment: @has19 do you have any sample code that I can follow?

Comment: tried it but the nested recyclerview only shows *one** item per recyclerview, the rest are not showing.

Comment: just google about nested recyelview you can find plenty of tutorials

Answer (score 0):

The key thing that I needed to do is to set the `planItemView` **id** to an id that's never used in my app. so I created a number constant that's unlikely to be used by other Views, and use it as a base for the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc. plan item view.

After that the `RelativeLayout` root is showing the individual `plan item view` correctly.

1. add to top of class

   ```
   companion object {
       private const val BASE_PLAN_ITEM_ID = 164
   }
   ```
2. Update method

   ```
   private fun PlanItem.addToRootView(
       rootView: RelativeLayout,
       pos: Int,
       r: Resources
   ) {
       val planItemView: ConstraintLayout = inflater
           .inflate(R.layout.new_plan, rootView, false) as ConstraintLayout

       planItemView.id = BASE_PLAN_ITEM_ID + pos

       with(planItemView) {
           tv_title.text = name
           tv_desc.setTextAndGoneIfEmpty(description)
           tv_date.text = getDateToDisplay(resources)
           tv_subject.setTextAndGoneIfEmpty(subject?.name)
       }

       val params = planItemView.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams

       val idOfBelow: Int

       if (planItemView.id > BASE_PLAN_ITEM_ID) {
           idOfBelow = planItemView.id - 1

           // If it is the 2nd or more item in the list, add a margin above it
           params.setMargins(
               params.leftMargin,
               calculatePx(16, r),
               params.rightMargin,
               params.bottomMargin
           )
       } else {
           idOfBelow = rootView.id
       }
       params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, idOfBelow)

       rootView.addView(planItemView, params)
   }
   ```